# Java Do While loop issue

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

*Edited, only having an issue with the pot value not looping.*

I'm having a problem with my loop in a simple gambling game I'm developing. The game does everything I want it to, up to the point where it loops back. I don't want the pot to reset back to the static $100 amount I set. **It's also not giving new dice rolls. FIXED (Thanks Prodian).** It seems like the loop will keep resetting back to the original amount and will not take the last round into consideration. I have a feeling it's just a matter of wrong variable placement, but I've tried moving them around and I just can't wrap my head around a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class gamblinggame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random ran = new Random();

        double bet;
        double pot = 100;
        int r1 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int r2 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int r3 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

        System.out.println("*** Gambling Game ***");
        System.out.println("Your starting pot is $100, please place a bet less than or equal to the pot.");

        do {

             r1 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1; // continues to re-roll dice
             r2 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
             r3 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

            bet = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (bet > pot) {
                System.out.println("Invalid amount. Please place a new bet.");
                continue;
            }
            if (bet >= 1) {
                System.out.println("Your new pot is $" + (pot - bet) + ".");
                System.out.println("Rolling the dice.");
                System.out.println(
                        "You rolled " + r1 + ", " + r2 + ", " + r3 + ".  The total amount rolled is " + (r1 + r2 + r3));
                if (r1 == r2 || r1 == r3 || r2 == r3) {
                    System.out.println("You win DOUBLE your bet back!");
                    System.out.println("Your new pot is $" + (pot + (bet * 2)) + ".");
                } else if (r1 == r2 && r1 == r3 && r2 == r3) {
                    System.out.println("You win TRIPLE your bet back!");
                    System.out.println("Your new pot is $" + (pot + (bet * 3)) + ".");
                } else if (r1 + r2 + r3 >= 10) {
                    System.out.println("You win your bet back!");
                    System.out.println("Your new pot is $" + (pot) + ".");
                }
                System.out.println("Enter a new bet equal to or below the pot.");
            }


            if (bet > pot) {
                System.out.println("Invalid amount. Please place a new bet.");
                continue;
            } 
            if (bet == 0) {
                System.out.println("Game Over. Please play again!");
            break;
            }
        } while (pot > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never re-roll the dice.

Comment: You have `pot = startingPot - bet;` inside the loop.  It's always based off of the starting pot, no matter how many bets you've done.

Answer (score 1):

you should re-roll dice, the solution of re-roll is:

```
....
int r1 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1; 
int r2 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
int r3 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
....
do{
 r1 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1; // again random at the start of do-while loop is necessary
 r2 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
 r3 = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;
....
}.....
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that doing it with an array: `int[] rs = ran.ints(3, 1, 7);` is an alternative (and that the roll values aren't required outside the loop, and so the bit before the `do` is unnecessary).

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Now I'm just having an issue with the pot amount.

Comment: My English is not enough good to understand or I do not know what is pot. What should pot do ? What is pot. Tell me what it should do, then I can can answer for pot too.